# addview fail when inflate and setContentview same layout

Tags: android, view

I want to add a `View` but it can't display the `View` and no error found when run

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.relative_null);
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout= (RelativeLayout)
            getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.relative_null,null);
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Hello World");
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
            (80,80);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,R.id.button1);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,R.id.button1);
    tv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    relativeLayout.addView(tv);
}
```

And this is my xml `R.layout.relative_null`

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"   
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/myRelativeLayout">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button1"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Not sure what your question is, but you have to use setContentView(relativeLayout) at the end of onCreate, or you won't see a thing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't really adding the textview properly. You are adding the textview to a layout that you yourself inflated. That layout is different from the one that you see via `setContentView()`. You don't need to inflate another. Here's the updated code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.relative_null);
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.myRelativeLayout);

    // tv init below
    TextView tv = new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("Hello World");
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams
            (80,80); 
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF,R.id.button1);
    layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,R.id.button1);
    tv.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    relativeLayout.addView(tv);
}
```

Comment: really  thank you  and could you tell me why That layout is different from the one that you see via setContentView().they came from same layout file

Comment: The single layout file is getting inflated twice: once by you (instance1) and the other time in `setContentView()`(instance2). So, now you have two instance of it. Notice that you were adding the view to instance1(which you can't really see) and trying to find it in instance2 (which you see in your phone).